# .fadeOut() in Firefox

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I've added a fadeOut() function to my element and when I inspect the element I actually see the numbers for opacity decrease, and when they come to 0, the element simply disappears, instead of slowly fading out. If that a FF bug?

Here's my code

```
setTimeout(function () {  
    $('#myEm').toggleClass('in').delay('3000').fadeOut('slow',  function() {
           $(this).remove();
    });
}, 100);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j38tswgu/)

Comment: Can you post a complete example and a fiddle?

Comment: Works fine here http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: What versions of Jquery/Firefox?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/2012/02/jquery-fadeout-in-firefox-10/ . he is having the same problem in firefox 10 until version 13 because there is is fixed

Comment: I'm using the latest FF version: 37.0.2.

Comment: @j08691 Added jsFiddle.

Comment: Why don't you remove the JS stuff and do the animation entirely in CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/j38tswgu/3/ With animating all properties, the opacity animation cannot finish properly in Chrome as well.

Comment: @Christoph This is a tiny part of my JS. I actually need it to build an entire page with a lot of static and dynamic elements.

Comment: I see. In any case I would avoid mixing. I'd propose you either do all your animation with CSS or JS. Otherwise you will lose overview pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `transition`. The solution is really easy.

```
#myEm {
 top:-100px;
 z-index: 99999;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin-left: 45%;
 margin-right:50%;
 transition: top 1s ease; /*only animate the top and not all*/
 -webkit-transition: top 1s ease; /*this is so that is will also work on google chrome*/
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/j38tswgu/2/) you have a working fiddle. (I removed the delay just to show it quickly)